# timeIntervalSinceDate inside an if statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

my code is crashing because of this problem:

```
if ([recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]==0 )
{       
    NSLog(@"we are recording now because signal is at high volume... ");
    if(flag==1)
    {
        start = [NSDate date];       
    }
    [recorder stop];            
}
else 
{
    [recorder stop];    
    stop = [NSDate date];
    duration = [start timeIntervalSinceDate:stop];
```

stop and start are NSDate and declared at the start of the .m
,The problem is that because "duration" and "start" are not in the same "if", and moving "start" to be under the "else" solve it. but i need it to be there.

why is that happen? the software is going for sure to the "start" before she goes to the stop, so does he forget the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[NSDate date]` gives a autoreleased object to the caller. 
Change `start = [NSDate date];` to `start = [[NSDate date] retain];` and you should be fine.

Then you have to balance the retain counts in the end.

Comment: +1 this is the reason why app crashes.@Rant see your console there was a log of badAccess .

Comment: thanks a lot! works great.. What do you mean by balance the retain?? release it on the delloc ?

Comment: another thing, i get numbers such 1006632960 or -67108864 what is that?  the nslog  times are so defferent....

Comment: Make sure that the duration is an CGFloat or a float. And by "balancing the retain count" I mean you have to decide where you release the memory which is retained in "start ... retain];". The implementation depends on the rest of your code. Maybe a "[start release];" before the "start = ..." fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Move initialization of start before the if statement. That way it will always be valid.